# Custom message in devise invitable email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How do you pass a custom message to the devise invitable email? I want the inviter to include a message to the invitee, like "Hey check out this site".

I tried both including it in the attributes and setting an instance variable in the block, neither seem to be accessible from the email.

```
  user = User.invite!(:email => share.to_user_email, :message => "hey check this out") do 
    @message = "hey it's me!"
  end
```

Comment: Whoops, never trust spell check...

Comment: would you mind to accept the answer if it is ok? thanx in advance

Comment: Don't forget check config.scoped_views = true
in Devise config. Without it new views wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 12):

you have to do `rails generate devise_invitable:views users`

then you will get new erb file `app/views/users/mailer/invitation_instructions.html.erb` which you will be able to customize in any way you want

Comment: in current devise version it should be app/views/devise/mailer/invitation_instructions.html.erb

Comment: what if i am taking an input message from user? How can i put it into the view?

Comment: you should ask new SO question.. just point me to it and i will try to help.. it is difficult to share code inside comments

Comment: I am facing this same issue can any one please answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806998/how-to-send-custom-invitation-using-devise-invitable

Comment: so when I generated views using `bin/rails g devise_invitable:views users`, it creates inside `app/views/users/mailer` instead of `app/views/devise/mailer` and `views/users/mailer` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

Email template will allow you to send same message for all the emails.

Here is another way/case, when you are taking message as an input from user.

model/user.rb

```
attr_accessor :message
```

controller

```
  User.invite!({email: email}, current_user) do |user|
    user.message = params[:message]
  end
```

/views/devise/mailer/invitation_instructions.html.erb

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p><%= @resource.message%>.</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

the content of the mail is in app/views/devise/mailer/invitation_instructions.html.erb. By default it is:

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has invited you to <%= root_url %>, you can accept it through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Accept invitation', accept_invitation_url(@resource, :invitation_token => @resource.invitation_token) %></p>

<p>If you don't want to accept the invitation, please ignore this email.<br />
Your account won't be created until you access the link above and set your password.</p>
```

modify this file to customize.